# How to send list of dictionary from flask to javascript/template and convert it to a JSON

Tags: javascript, flask

```
def prediction():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        keyword = request.form['text']
        tweet_list = get_tweets(keyword)
        include_neutral = True
        result_list = []
        for i in range(len(tweet_list)):
            start_at = time.time()
            # Tokenize text
            text = tweet_list[i]
            x_test = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text]), maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
            # Predict
            score = model.predict([x_test])[0]
            # Decode sentiment
            label = decode_sentiment(score, include_neutral=include_neutral)
            result = {"tweet": tweet_list[i],"label": label, "score": float(score), "elapsed_time": time.time()-start_at}
            result_list.append(result)    
        return render_template('prediction.html', result = json.dumps(result_list))
    return render_template("index.html")
```

I am sending a list of dictionary.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

<title>Prediction | Sentiment Analysis</title>

{% endblock %}


{% block body %}



<div id="prediction"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{{result | tojson | safe}}'));
   var pre = document.getElementById('prediction');
   pre.innerHTML = res;
   console.log(res, typeof(res));
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

In this template I am able to print the result but even after parsing the result to JSON the

```
console.log(typeof(res))
```

Gives string as output.

How to convert it into json and iterate/loop through it?

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` on what should already be a JSON string? Just omit that and I would hope this works.

Comment: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 4 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) ```Getting this error in console after doing that

Comment: Because a regular list is not a valid JSON. Change your result to valid JSON.

Comment: What is the other way to send a list of dict as json? How do i do that?